# Swift - Can't access properties of decodable struct

Tags: arrays, json, swift, struct

I'm trying to access the "start" and "end" properties of the "Market" struct (last struct). Here's the data model:

```
struct MarketHours: Decodable {
        let equity: Equity
    }
    
    struct Equity: Decodable {
        let eq: EQ?
        enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
            case eq = "EQ"
        }
    }
    
    struct EQ: Decodable {
        let sessionHours: SessionHours
    }
    
    struct SessionHours: Decodable {
        let regularMarket: [Market]
    }
    
    struct Market: Decodable {
        let start: String
        let end: String
    }
```

Everything is working perfectly fine up to that point, I'm even able to access the data from "Market" as a whole...

```
let something: () = GetMarketHours(completion: {
    result in
    switch result {
    case.success(let output):
        let somethingElse = output.equity.eq?.sessionHours.regularMarket
        print(somethingElse)
    case.failure(_):
        return
    }
})
            
// "somethingElse" prints:

[{start "2020-08-10T09:30:00-04:00", end "2020-08-10T16:00:00-04:00"}]
```

...just not its properties "start" and "end" by themselves. Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like you typed regularMarket as an array of Market

Comment: Yes, an array containing "start" and "end". Is there any other way I could code that?

Comment: You need to iterate over your markets or if you just have one element `let regularMarket = output.equity.eq?.sessionHours.regularMarket.first`

Comment: I now changed the "somethingElse" constant to something like: `let somethingElse = output.equity.eq!.sessionHours.regularMarket[0].start` and it worked. I've tried that before but but it never worked. It turns out that all I needed to do was to change `eq?` to `eq!`.